# How can I list all users who can su into a generic account

Tags: sudo, su

I have a generic account several users can su into, I however would like to find the name of all users who can do this.

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: You might want to provide some more detail.  How about the type and version of UNIX you're referring to, also, you tag su and sudo, do you mean just `su`, or do you mean people can `sudo su` into the account?

Answer (score 1):

`su` allows you to access someone's account if

- You're root or
- You know their password

There's no way to list what users know another users password (and if you could, you should revoke all their access. Users should *never* give out their password, for any reason, to anyone, including IT).

---

`sudo` grants an account authorization to access another account. Instead of knowing the password on the target account, users must know (and enter) *their* password, to prove who they are. This access is also logged, and you can manage the access lists with the `/etc/sudoers` file (use the command `visudo` to actually edit it, don't edit it directly!)

You can read about the format of the `sudoers` file with `man sudoers`. Usually, a group is granted sudo access (such as `admin` or `wheel` or `sudo`), and then users are added to that group, and you can list the users in that group to find out who has access.

Comment: https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html